# Return array to .get call from a Django View?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm quite new to Django and jQuery and I'm having trouble getting data from my Django models into my jQuery.

```
My Django models look like this:

class Exercise(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    rounds = models.IntegerField()

class Task(models.Model):
    Exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    solution = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    difficulty_level = models.IntegerField()
```

My jQuery:

```
var tasks = [];

// set up tasks
tasks.push(task("hun kaldes lilletøs","hun kaldes Lilletøs","Ret sætningen nedenfor, så der bliver stavet med store bogstaver efter reglerne.","Help tekst","Feedback tekst","2"));
tasks.push(task("john johnson","John Johnson","Ret sætningen nedenfor, så der bliver stavet med store bogstaver efter reglerne.","Help tekst","Feedback tekst","1"));
tasks.push(task("han hedder bent","han hedder Bent","Ret sætningen nedenfor, så der bliver 

function task(text,solution, description, help, feedback, level){
    return {
        text:text,
        solution:solution,
        description:description,
        help:help,
        feedback:feedback,
        level:level,
    }
}
```

I created the jQuery first, and I'm therefor hoping that there's a way to get the Django data into my data structure in jQuery. The rest of my jQuery is very dependant on having the data in this format.

**Here's what I have so far:**
From my searches I've identified two different possible methods. Parsing the data directly into the jQuery via Django's template language or loading the data via ajax. I don't know which method is most efficient, and how exactly one should go about this best, but for some reasons it seems to me that using ajax would be the best solution.

The jQuery .load method doesn't seem like the best fit, since it's built to load data directly into HTML.

The jQuery .get method might be able to do it. Here's what I've tried doing:

`Views.py`:

```
def get_tasks(request):
    task_list = Task.objects.filter(Exercise_id=1)
    return HttpResponse(task_list)
```

`jQuery`:

```
$.get( "/get_tasks" )
            .done(function( data ) {
                var test = []
                test.push(data);
                alert(test)
            });
```

The ajax itself works. The data is retrieved, but it only shows the unicode representation, not the object. This is probably because I should return it in another way than HttpResponse, I just havn't figured out how to do this.

So the question is, how do I return an array to a jQuery .get call from a Django view?

EDIT:

```
Here's the code I have so far, it's giving me a 500 error with the jQuery call though    

import simplejson
from django.http import HttpResponse
def get_tasks(request):
    task_list = Task.objects.filter(Exercise_id=1)
    tasklist = dict((x.id, {
        'task': x.task,
        'solution': x.solution,
        }) for x in task_list)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict(isOk=1,tasklist=tasklist)))
```

Comment: If you have DEBUG=True, you should be able to see see the Django debug message using Chrome, via Developer tools > Network > <request> > Response.

Answer (score 2):

**Your view look like this**

```
import simplejson
def get_tasks(request):
    task_list = Task.objects.filter(Exercise_id=1)
    tasklist = dict((x.id, {
        'field1': x.your_filed_name1,
        'field2': x.your_filed_name2,
    }) for x in task_list.iterator())
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict(isOk=1,tasklist=tasklist)))
```

**your jQuery look like this**

```
$.get( "/get_tasks" )
            .done(function( data ) {
                console.log(data.tasklist)
            });
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried implementing this, and I'm getting an invalid syntax error at exception location "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35". Exception is thrown at the last line of the view. I've checked that simplejson is installed, but can't really figure out what the error is.

Comment: can you past you code here. so will figure out and correct. and please check last line : return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict(isOk=1,tasklist=tasklist))) is correct.

Comment: Ahh yeah, of course, here it is:
import simplejson
def get_tasks(request):
    task_list = Task.objects.filter(Exercise_id=1)
    tasklist = dict((x.id, {
        'text': x.text,
        'solution': x.solution,
    }) for x in task_list.iterator())
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict(isOk=1,tasklist=tasklist)))

Comment: change code is: import simplejson
from django.http import HttpResponse
def get_tasks(request): 
    task_list = Task.objects.filter(Exercise_id=1)
    tasklist = dict((x.id, 
        { 
        'text': x.text,
        'solution': x.solution,
        }) for x in task_list)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict(isOk=1,tasklist=tasklist)))

Comment: Please use proper indent. code is working if you still getting error. you bedbug this code using import pdb;pdb.set_trac()

Comment: The view is working now, but the .get call is giving a 500 error. I've updated by posts to put the code you supplied in the bottom.

Comment: You can use This code for call ajax: 
$.ajax({
 url:"/get_tasks/",
 method:"GET",
 success:function(data){
        console.log(data.tasklist)
  }});

or also you test current code just placing url like "/get_tasks/".

Comment: I've got it working now. I'll update my code once I've finished with the details, thanks fory our help @Yogesh!

Answer (score 1):

> Parsing the data directly into the jQuery via Django's template
>   language or loading the data via AJAX. I don't know which method is
>   most efficient

You should use ajax, if the data you fetch from the server depends on some user choices on the page or if the amount of data is huge and would otherwise slow the loading of the page. Otherwise use Django templating instead to load the values into your javascript.

If you do need AJAX, I recommend checking out http://www.dajaxproject.com/. It's a nice little library to simplify AJAX-calls in Django.

Here's how it would look with Dajaxice (with the added example of passing parameters from the page to Django):

app/ajax.py:

```
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from django.utils import simplejson
from app.models import Task

@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
def get_tasks(request, exercise_id):
    task_list = Task.objects.filter(Exercise_id=exercise_id)
    return simplejson.dumps(task_list)
```

JS:

```
function get_tasks_callback(data){
    console.log(data);
}
var params = {'exercise_id': 1}
Dajaxice.app.get_tasks(get_tasks_callback, params);
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice to have some more basis than simply my gut feeling. I'll stick to ajax. I'll have a look at dajaxproject and see if i can figure it out :-)